# How to get the string inside single quotes?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a sample string like 
**http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')**

from this I need to get 
**http://www.genworth.com/%20**

Regex I used was `/'(.*?)'/`

The code I tried was

```
<cfset link = "http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')">
<cfset matches = REMatch("/'(.*?)'/", link) /> 
<cfdump var="#matches#">
```

But its returning an empty array. What am I missing?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/920zhgn2/) in which I tried the RegEx

Comment: Try `<cfset matches = REMatch("'([^']*)", link) />`. Access the captured text in Group 1.

Comment: @stribizhev your anser helped me. It was not fully correct but I made a solution fron it. Thank you.

Comment: Please check the code I adapted from another site. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a Coldfusion question I will offer a Coldfusion answer without overcomplicating it with a RegEx :-)

```
<cfset link = "http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')" />
<cfset matches = ListGetAt(link, 2, "'") />
<cfdump var="#matches#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your single quotes:

```
var str = "http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')"; 
var res = str.match(/\'(.*?)\'/);
alert(res[1])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s865b5bn/2/

Good luck!!

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. I have updated it with your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/s865b5bn/1/ its the same result

Comment: Change `res[0]` to `res[1]`.

Comment: <cfset matches = REMatch("/\'(.*?)\'/", link) /> is not working for me. Its returning empty array. In js its working but in coldfusion its returning empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Any way I found the solution. I dont think it is proper. But still it works.

```
<cfset link = "http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')">
<cfset matches = REMatch("'([^']*)", link) />
<cfset matches = Right(matches[1], Len(matches[1])-1) />
<cfdump var="#matches#">
```

**OR**

```
<cfset link = "http://ezsearch.annuitynexus.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.genworth.com/%20')">
<cfset matches = REMatch("'(.*?)'", link) /> 
<cfdump var="#matches#">
```

works fine. But in this output is something like **'http://www.genworth.com/%20'** so I need to remove first and last character

Answer (score 0):

You need not add the regex delimiters `/.../` in coldfusion regex. It is also advisable to turn the lazy dot matching to a negated character class so that the regex becomes more efficient.

Use

```
<cfset matches = REMatch("'([^']*)", link) />
```

Note that `[^']` matches any character other than a single apostrophe.

The match is inside the capture group 1.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS5fZ2/1)

Comment: Ok, I see. I reverted to just the expression as it was before. BTW, is look-behind supported? I think it can be since it is using Java regex. Try just `(?<=')[^']+`.